# Filter Dropdown Slicer on Chart Interaction Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dropdown

Im trying to filter some dropdown selections based on the Drill Down Donut Chart from Power BI Marketplace. However this seems to be impossible with the current features in Power BI, which leads me to the question - Does anyone know of a way to filter slicers from other charts, or create a dropdown using another visual type?

If you need more details let me know!

Cheers!
Kalrin

**UPDATE**

I have included a gif to go in more detail about this question.
[image]
As shown above, when i click a selection on the donut drill chart, I want the slicer drop-downs to show which item (Customer->Therapist->Citizen) is selected in the respective dropdowns.

As it stands now, the only way I see as a possible solution is to create your own custom visual. Slicers seems to be impossible to filter by other charts.
If i change my dropdowns to matrix or other charts, it works as intended.

The dropdowns in the market works in terms of filtering to a single element, but the visual does not change the 'placeholder' when only containing a single value.

My issue is only about the visualisation of the data, because the dataset itself updates on interactions as intended.

Comment: One slicer can filter another slicer, but I have not seen visuals filter slicers the way they can filter each other.

Comment: Would be nice to have some sort of dropdown that could have selected value based on another chart. Its more of a visual design issue to me, that I have to use, for instance, a matrix visual to show it.. Maybe its not possible without a custom visual. I tried the two dropdown visuals available on the market. They look a bit silly, but they can filter on other charts. The selected value tho, does not show up as first in the dropdown - it still says 'all'. 

I will update this question during the day though, with a more detailed explanation of what I want.